# pandas giving Unsupported Operation: truncate() for writing data frame in Excel file

Tags: python, pandas, unsupportedoperation

I am using pandas to write my data frames into an Excel file. I have written a function that helps me write the data frame into an Excel file.
This is the function:

```
def touch_excel(
        df: pd.DataFrame,
        file_path: str,
        sheet_name: str = "Sheet1",
        add_df: pd.DataFrame = None):
    """
        this function concatenates two data frames (if given),
        and converts them into an Excel file at the given location

        Args:
            df (pandas.DataFrame): the data frame to be written into the Excel file
            file_path (str): the path to the Excel file
            sheet_name (str): the name of the sheet in the Excel file
            add_df (pandas.DataFrame): the additional data frame to be concatenated
    """
    if add_df is not None:
        df = pd.concat([df, add_df], ignore_index=True)

    try:
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            df.to_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
        else:
            with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
    except PermissionError:
        raise Exception("File might be open. Close it.")
```

Now, this function runs in almost all my cases, but for some cases it gives Unsupported Operation message and stops the program execution. Why is it happening? Could someone explain?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\PR-Dashboard-Automation\main.py", line 512, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\Projects\PR-Dashboard-Automation\main.py", line 130, in main
    touch_excel(df, data_file, 'Previous Data')
  File "E:\Projects\PR-Dashboard-Automation\main.py", line 27, in touch_excel
    with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
  File "E:\Projects\PR-Dashboard-Automation\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1370, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "E:\Projects\PR-Dashboard-Automation\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1374, in close
    self._save()
  File "E:\Projects\PR-Dashboard-Automation\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 113, in _save
    self._handles.handle.truncate()
io.UnsupportedOperation: truncate
```

I tried to solve the problem by changing the paths to the folder, also I tried to use other methods like setting the workbook manually. But still it doesn't fixed the problem. But whenever I use

```
mode = 'r'
```

instead of

```
mode = 'a'
```

It starts working, but doesn't create multiple sheets in the same Excel file.
(Asking since this code runs for almost all the programs except some cases)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looks like a version problem. Try updating Pandas: pip install --upgrade pandas

Comment: I tried to use different versions of pandas, from latest to older versions. But it still doesn't fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

is openpyxl installed in your system? 
if no:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

if yes:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas openpyxl
```

and also, in this code block:

```
else:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, mode='a', engine='openpyxl', 
        if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
```

you can try to change engine type from openpyxl to **xlsxwriter**
so it will be something like this:

```
else:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, mode='a', engine='xlsxwriter', 
        if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
```

Comment: I tried to use 'xlsxwriter'. It solved the problem for some programs, but for larger codes, it again started giving the truncate() error. I will try to find some more solutions to the problem. Thanks :)